# C++ DirectX First Person Camera

Tags: c++, matrix, camera, directx

I'm trying to make a first person camera. At the moment, I'm working on the x and y rotation.
The rotation is defined by the mouse offset from the center of the window.

```
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(g_hWnd, &rc);
UINT width = rc.left + (rc.right - rc.left) / 2;
UINT height = rc.top + (rc.bottom - rc.top) / 2;

POINT pt;
GetCursorPos(&pt);

int xMouseDelta = pt.x - width;
int yMouseDelta = pt.y - height;

g_View = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f) *
    XMMatrixRotationX(yMouseDelta / 100) *
    XMMatrixRotationY(xMouseDelta / 100);
```

The problem is, when moving it falters. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If I change the "100" (the sensitivity) to a higher number I don't see anything at all.

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the matrices, but I'm not sure. Or maybe the "GetCursorPos()" function isn't that precise?

Excuse me for my bad English. Thank you for reading!

Comment: are you sure you should use `XMMatrixRotationX(yMouseDelta / 100)` and `XMMatrixRotationY(xMouseDelta / 100)` instead of `XMMatrixRotationX(xMouseDelta / 100)` and `XMMatrixRotationY(yMouseDelta / 100)`

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the deltas as `int`. Therefore, `delta / 100` is also an `int` which allows angles of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` radians and their negatives. Just convert them to `float`:

```
XMMatrixRotationX(yMouseDelta / 100.0f)
```